# perl inline: autosplit does not splits ls command into @F array

Tags: perl

```
ls | perl -anle 'print $F[0]' -> file1\nfile2\nfile3\n ...
```

This prints all files of `ls`. But is shouldn't. I want to access to ar `@F`, and `ls` gives file separated by space, so each file should be one element of `@F`, according to this:

```
-a   turns on autosplit mode when used with a -n or -p.  An implicit
            split command to the @F array is done as the first thing inside the
            implicit while loop produced by the -n or -p.
```

So I would like to access only first element, because if I change to `$F[1]` in print statement, then no ouput. I would expect `file2`. How does `-a` work then? (yes I have read documentation)

Edit:
If I use `l`, then after pipe, output won't be separate by `"\n"`, so I can do the prior command with `l` listing instead.

Comment: Seems like the output of `ls` is not separated by space, but by newlines when `ls` is not connected to a tty. Try using: `ls | perl -0777 -ane 'print "$F[0]\n"'` instead

Comment: That works, but what actually is the value `777`, new line?

Comment: @Herdsman See [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlrun.html#Command-Switches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `ls` is not separated by space, but by newlines when `ls` is not connected to a tty.

See [Output from ls has newlines but displays on a single line. Why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10421/45537).

You can try using:

```
ls | perl -0777 -ane 'print "$F[0]\n"'
```

instead. This will set the input record separator to slurp the whole file, and then split that string on white space into `@F`.

Comment: Where are documented all values for separator '$/'?

Comment: @Herdsman See [perldoc perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for the `-0` switch

Comment: Use `ls -C` to force multi-column output (or `ls -1` for single column output) whether or not the output is a tty.

Comment: Should add `-F\\n` to handle paths with whitespace. As is, your solution doesn't handle path with spaces in them, a relatively common occurrence.

Answer (score 3):

The output of `ls` is not separated by spaces but by line feeds (as if `-1` had been used) when sending its output to something other than a terminal.

```
$ ls | cat
bar
foo
```

(See [Output from ls has newlines but displays on a single line. Why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10421/45537) for more info.)

In order to populate an array with each line of input, I would use

```
perl -F\\n -0777ane'...'
```

or the more readable

```
perl -e'chomp(@F=<>); ...'
```

For example,

```
$ ls | perl -e'chomp(@F=<>); CORE::say "<$_>" for @F;'
<bar>
<foo>
```

Both of these solutions handles paths that contains spaces. (It only has problems with paths that contains line feeds.)

That said, using `ls` isn't really appropriate. One could use a call to `glob` to the list of files even more easily and without any downsides.

```
perl -e'@F=<*>; ...'
```

For example,

```
$ perl -e'@F=<*>; CORE::say "<$_>" for @F;'
<bar>
<foo>
```

Comment: how about `@F=<*>`

Comment: @ysth, I didn't know if `ls` was actually being used or not, and whether if had arguments or not. If they're using a plain `ls`, then that would be a great alternative. Still, I should have mentioned it anyway. Done.